# How to use build wrapper with sonar lint?

Tags: c, eclipse, sonarlint

I'm using sonarlint for a C project on eclipse oxygen 4.7.0 and sonarlint 3.2.0 on linux.

I try to use sonar build wrapper with sonarlint, but when I add the property: sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw_output as shown in the image below, I don't get anything displayed in sonarlint report.

[sonarlint analyser properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmb45.png)

Here below an extract of the sonarlint console with build wrapper activated:

> Using build-wrapper output:
>   /home/developpeur/workspace/aulnoye-vog-pulse_indus-c/bw_output/build-wrapper-dump.json
>   Execute Sensor: XmlFileSensor 0 compilation units analyzed Found 0 issue(s)

When I remove the property sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output, I get a sonarlint report and this in the console:

> Execute Sensor: XmlFileSensor Found 11719 issue(s)
>   Download server issues for project aulnoye-vog-pulse_indus-c
>   26 compilation units analyzed

I'd like to use build wrapper because there are lot of false detections of this rule ***"Make the prototype of this function visible at this point"*** when I run an analyse without it. These false detections disappear when I run an analyse with sonar-scanner and build wrapper.

What can prevent me to get results in sonarlint report with build wrapper?